# Writing SEH translator

Tags: c++, winapi, exception, seh

```
class seh_exception : public std::exception {
public:   
    seh_exception(UINT se_code, PEXCEPTION_POINTERS se_info);
    seh_exception(const seh_exception& old);
    ~seh_exception();

    const char *what() const;
};

void translate_seh_exception(UINT se_code, PEXCEPTION_POINTERS se_info) {
    throw seh_exception(se_code, se_info);
}
```

Now, what do I do in the constructor? I couldn't find any information on how long `*se_info` will exist, which means that I probably shouldn't just save `se_info` in a private field for later use — I should deeply copy it. Or maybe not?

And what's with `what()`? Am I supposed to conjure the underlying string on-demand? Again, allocating memory in the constructor seems not a very good idea in this case.

I've currently implemented it storing `se_code` and `se_info` without any deep-copying, and generating formatted message in the constructor, and it works, though I do not know if it is actually *supposed* to work.

I intend to use it in "catch, log what happened, terminate" scenario.

Comment: I would suggest that you TRY to implement something, and see where the CATCH is ... Pun's inevitably intentional...

Comment: @MatsPetersson I wrote it already: with shallow-copying and message-formatting in the constructor. It works. But that doesn't mean it works *reliably*.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `what` is typically solved by a switch where each case returns a literal string. It's quite a while since I worked on Windows systems, so can't really help with the others. However, my point with my comment was that "If you show the code", it makes for a much more detailed view of how it actually works, and people can spot errors/mistakes/problems.

Comment: There is *very* little you can do reliably when you catch an SEH.  Allocating memory is not an option, the heap may be locked.  Better keep some memory set aside at program initialization.  And do the absolute minimum when you format the what() string, best to do nothing at all beyond copying the exception info.  Or just not catch *everything*, you don't want to pass, say, an access violation exception to arbitrary C++ code in a catch block that won't have a clue how to recover from that.

Comment: Also, don't catch any exception unless you either want to do a little cleanup and then re-throw (in which case you can just `catch(...){/*cleanup*/ throw;}` which will handle SEH exceptions just fine), or unless you ***actually know what to do with the exception***.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need your own class just to achieve this, you can just throw the `PEXCEPTION_POINTERS`. `se_code` is also available at `se_info->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode`.

So the simplest handler is just;

```
void translate_seh_exception(UINT se_code, PEXCEPTION_POINTERS se_info) {
    throw se_info;
}
```

You can then `catch(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS se_info)`

The `EXCEPTION_POINTERS` is guaranteed to exist for the duration of the `catch` block, which is how long you need it for. As per the documentation, your translator function is called once for each catch block, that is, it has to re-translate the SEH exception for every function containing a `try/catch` block.